# Fast query to retrieve those records that has published date

Tags: linq, sitecore, sitecore7

How do I query using Sitecore fast query to retrieve those records that has published date? I tried using the below but it did not return any value. 
And how do I retrieve only the last node? Because when I use descendant::*, it will also return the parent out.

> fast:/sitecore/content/test//*[@@parentid='{5656C582-A876-41E6-8441-A3F0BA0D2601}'
>   and @Publish>'20170101T000000']/descendant::*

Answer (score 0):

The Sitecore Field name for the publish field is not `Publish`. You need to make use of the following syntax for publish field: `@__Publish`.

You can see the right field name in the Inheritance from the template. You will be able to see the field names as shown below:

[image]

So, your query will looks as follows:

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@parentid='{5656C582-A876-41E6-8441-A3F0BA0D2601}' and @__Publish > '20170101T000000']/*
```